# Query run in Amazon Redshift runs in my machine's local memory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, inner-join

I am trying to join a rather big table (approx 100 million rows) in Amazon Redshift. When I use SQLWorkbench/J to send the command to Amazon to join the table with a reference table, it runs the query in my machine's local memory.

I did some research on it and found that it may be the timeout settings on my machine (MacOSX), so I changed those as directed but it is still running the JOIN query in memory, which obviously cannot handle this many rows.

Has anyone experienced this? Why would it be running in local memory?

The SQL code I'm using is:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.ref=table2.ref;
```

Answer (score 2):

As Alex mentioned above, your local computer is not running the join, but rather attempting to display the results. I can't comment yet, but I would like to direct you to Redshift's [unload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html) functionality if you *really* need the entire result set of that join to be returned.

After you've tested your join with a small sample of data and confirmed that it is returning the correct set, you can run `unload` to dump the results of the query to your s3 directory along with a manifest file that lets you know what files were created (if the dataset was too large for one file):

```
unload ('SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.ref=table2.ref')
to 's3://YOUR_BUCKET/EXPORT' credentials 
'aws_access_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>'
manifest;
```

Then you can download the files as needed without having your SQL workbench panic.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be running the join in memory, the sql will be executed on the redshift node(s). Your problem will be you are trying to return 100 million rows with your "select *". Sql workbench is going to struggle to render that much data.

Limit your result set to reduce the number of rows being rendered, ie:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.ref=table2.ref limit 100
```

Also, make sure your distribution and sort keys (ref in your example) are the same on both tables to boost performance